# openID connect server with spring-cloud-securiy

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect, spring-cloud-security

we am trying to use  open ID connect (OIDC) for authentication and authorization (AnA) for our micro-service architecture based on spring-cloud framework

As a part of requirement we want to achieve following:

- Integrate (OIDC) with SSO Federation as a Identity provider which we are using federation to authenticate users (staff id)
- How to customize access_token which in turn will be provided by a micro service (Authorization service)

I am looking at MITREid Connect as its based on spring framework and spring security

https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server

As a resutl of that, all requests to our services have to go through (OIDC) for (AnA)

I also check on https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/ as I understand the Zuul server will get an access_token to relay to proxied services. But our scenarios are different as  we want to expose other micro-services to external parties as well so that we want to have secure our services.

Any advices is highly appreciated.

Comment: [spring-oauth-server](https://github.com/authlete/spring-oauth-server) is another example that supports OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect on Spring Framework. See [Spring + OAuth 2.0 + OpenID Connect](https://medium.com/@darutk/spring-oauth-2-0-openid-connect-3341a6ed1f92) for details.

Comment: hi @TakahikoKawasaki  I am wondering that I can have a client to send a request to openid connect server (OIDC) using the API ( without the the web browse context). the reason I am asking is that I want to build a service whether client (a system or machine) can request a ID_token or access token using api such restful interface and once it have obtained  to tokens, then use that token to access resource server.

Comment: If you want to get an ID token without user interaction, add "prompt=none" to your authorization request. If the end-user has already logged in and has given consent in the past to the scopes you request, an ID token may be issued. This implies that even in this case, user interaction must have been performed at least once in the past. AFAIK, there is no standard way to get an ID token completely without user interaction. However, some OpenID provider implementations provide means to generate ID tokens / access tokens without user interaction.